# XiangQi (Chinese chess) textbook or video tutorial

Tags: books, xiangqi

I know how the pieces move and understand basics, like forks and pins. Now I am looking for additional tutorials in English. So far, I've only found this book: "Introduction to Chinese Chess (XiangQi) for International Chess Players".

Can you please suggest video tutorials or books in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book I learned from is [Chinese Chess: An Introduction to China's Ancient Game of Strategy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080483508X) by H. T. Lau.

The book is mostly examples and exercises. There could have been more explanatory text.